# PostgreSQL left join becomes extremely slow after adding a column to SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, database-performance

I'm used to work with materialized views and I didn't encounter any performance problems until now. I'm using PostgreSQL v9.4.5. So when I do a simple `LEFT JOIN` on a materialized view using a table all works fine until a certain amount of selected columns (currently ca. 56 columns total). When I add an additional column to the `SELECT` statement, the execution time jumps from 3 seconds to over 5 minutes which is weird and unacceptable.

I have tried it with different combinations of columns and it really seems to depend on the number and not on the types nor the data in the columns. Then I used the `EXPLAIN` statement to see what the planner is doing in both cases and I found that

```
Hash Left Join  (cost=115615.56..501280.28 rows=2159465 width=400) (actual time=1696.312..5210.677 rows=2159465 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (mv.fkey = tb.id)
  Buffers: shared hit=132206, temp read=45756 written=45754
  ->  Seq Scan on mv (cost=0.00..125290.65 rows=2159465 width=372) (actual time=0.005..288.453 rows=2159465 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=103696
  ->  Hash  (cost=58202.25..58202.25 rows=2969225 width=28) (actual time=1693.613..1693.613 rows=2969225 loops=1)
        Buckets: 524288  Batches: 2  Memory Usage: 89300kB
        Buffers: shared hit=28510, temp written=8987
        ->  Seq Scan on tb  (cost=0.00..58202.25 rows=2969225 width=28) (actual time=0.010..585.523 rows=2969225 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=28510
Planning time: 0.376 ms
Execution time: 5316.682 ms
```

turns into

```
Hash Right Join  (cost=257726.96..505730.81 rows=2159465 width=408) (actual time=13991.355..810029.353 rows=2159465 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (tb.id = mv.fkey)
  Buffers: shared hit=132206, temp read=368900 written=237830
  ->  Seq Scan on tb  (cost=0.00..58202.25 rows=2969225 width=36) (actual time=0.006..631.307 rows=2969225 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=28510
  ->  Hash  (cost=125290.65..125290.65 rows=2159465 width=372) (actual time=9442.991..9442.991 rows=2159465 loops=1)
        Buckets: 65536  Batches: 131072 (originally 8)  Memory Usage: 204367kB
        Buffers: shared hit=103696, temp written=61097
        ->  Seq Scan on mv  (cost=0.00..125290.65 rows=2159465 width=372) (actual time=0.005..357.327 rows=2159465 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=103696
Planning time: 0.329 ms
Execution time: 810230.707 ms
```

I do not understand why that change between hash left and hash right join happens nor if it is relevant to the problem. Creating indexes on tb.id and mv.fkey improves the performance but only for about 1 minute.
Here's my very simple query:

```
SELECT mv.*, tb.id, tb.ts, tb.f_score, tb.adress, tb.score, tb.decision, tb.rating 
-- , tb.rating_level -- that one changes everything
FROM mv 
LEFT JOIN tb on tb.id = mv.fkey
```

And here is the DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE tb (
    id int4 NOT NULL,
    ts timestamp NULL,
    f_score int4 NULL,
    adress text NULL,
    decision text NULL,
    score int4 NULL,
    rating text NULL,
    rating_level text NULL,
    risk_indicator int4 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT tb_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE mv (
    request_id int4 NOT NULL,
    customer_id text NULL,
    customer_category text NULL,
    id_document_type text NULL,
    nationality text NULL,
    gender text NULL,
    date_of_birth date NULL,
    active_postpaid_subscriptions_count int4 NULL,
    accumulated_customer_recurring_charges_value text NULL,
    agreement_start_date timestamp NULL,
    latest_agreement_start_date timestamp NULL,
    bill_payment_method text NULL,
    blacklisted_fraud text NULL,
    blacklisted_collection text NULL,
    created_at timestamp NULL,
    country text NULL,
    city text NULL,
    zip text NULL,
    order_id text NULL,
    order_type text NULL,
    includes_mnp int4 NULL,
    dealer_chain_code text NULL,
    dealer_chain_name text NULL,
    typed text NULL,
    order_channel text NULL,
    is_blacklisted int4 NULL,
    is_whitelisted int4 NULL,
    response_id int4 NULL,
    order_score int4 NULL,
    state text NULL,
    business_instruction_template_names text NULL,
    fkey int4 NULL,
    response_received int4 NULL,
    orderer_type text NULL,
    internal_score int4 NULL,
    external_final_score int4 NULL,
    final_score int4 NULL,
    payment_type text NULL,
    installment text NULL,
    simo text NULL,
    price_plan_market text NULL,
    product_name text NULL,
    one_time_fee numeric NULL,
    one_time_discount numeric NULL,
    recurring_fee float8 NULL,
    recurring_discount float8 NULL,
    down_payment_amount text NULL,
    allowed_postpaid_subscription_count int4 NULL,
    allowed_postpaid_with_prepayment_subscription_count int4 NULL,
    allowed_payment_methods text NULL,
    CONSTRAINT mv_pk PRIMARY KEY (request_id),
    CONSTRAINT mv_idx UNIQUE (fkey)
)
```

The mv has a row count of 2,159,791 (810 MB) whereas the tb has a row count of 2,969,402 (222 MB). As it is a `LEFT JOIN` on a unique key, the expected result should have the same amount of records as the mv itself.

How can I avoid this performance drop from happening while selecting all the columns from both tables?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the **complete** execution plans (the slow and the fast one) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** - _not_ just a "simple" explain as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to overcharge my post

Comment: We need lots of information to help you with this sort of performance problem. [Please read this.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info)

Comment: Normalize your data model. (54 columns was a red flag) BTW: you cannot have two constraints with the same name.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The constraint name was a typo. However, these are a DWH tables and thus intentionally denormalized. So could we say that there is a limit of number of columns for Postgres to work efficiently?

Comment: Probably addition of columns resulted in a lot more physical I/O (temp read=368900 written=237830). Can you try significantly increasing the work_mem for the session?